# Intuition behind the non-Borel Lusin example

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Among the concrete examples of a non-borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$, 
I know only the Lusin example.

This is the set $L$ of all irrational numbers whose 
continued fraction representation $(a_0,a_1,\cdots)$ is such that there exist
an infinite subsequence $(a_{k_0},a_{k_1},\cdots)$ such that each for all $j$, 
$a_{k_j}$ divides $a_{k_{j+1}}$.

Knowing this, I am totally unable to see why this set $L$ would not be Borel, is there some intuition behind this ? What is the idea behind the proof of this fact ?

Comment: The more natural examples of analytic non-Borel sets in Polish spaces have the disadvantage of being in Polish spaces other than $\mathbb R$.  Even this one is sort of artificially inserted into $\mathbb R$ by taking an example in the Baire space $\mathbb N^\mathbb N$ and using continued fractions to map it into $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I definitely don't think this is a good "first example" of an analytic non-Borel set. It does, however, make more sense when put in comparison with the standard example of a co-analytic, non-Borel set:

Given a binary relation $R$ on $\mathbb{N}$, we can code $R$ by a set $X_R\subseteq\mathbb{N}$: let $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ be a bijection from $\mathbb{N}^2$ to $\mathbb{N}$ (e.g. the [Cantor pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function)), and let $$X_R=\{\langle m, n\rangle: mRn\}.$$ Now for a property $\mathfrak{P}$ of relations, let $S_\mathfrak{P}$ be the family of sets coding relations with that property. E.g. $S_{\mbox{linear}}$ is the family of sets which code linear orders of $\mathbb{N}$, and so forth.

It's not hard to see that $S_{\mbox{linear}}$ is Borel, indeed closed. It turns out that a good way to get Borel sets of high complexity, and non-Borel sets, is to look at sets of the form $S_\mathfrak{P}$ for more complicated properties $\mathfrak{P}$.

One important property of relations is *well-foundedness*: call a relation $R$ well-founded if there is no infinite sequence $a_0R a_1R a_2R...$. And the associated family of sets is $S_{WF}$.

It's not hard to show that $S_{WF}$ is co-analytic. (Strictly speaking, I've described $S_{WF}$ as a subset of $2^\omega$, not $\mathbb{R}$; but it's easy to switch it over, e.g. via the standard bijection between $2^\omega$ and the middle-thirds Cantor set.) But it turns out that $S_{WF}$ is *not* Borel!

Why? Well, remember that the Borel sets are arranged in a *hierarchy*, indexed by countable ordinals (the $\Sigma^0_\alpha$ and $\Pi^0_\alpha$ sets, as $\alpha\in\omega_1$). Now, a well-founded relation has a *rank* - a countable ordinal that measures how complicated it is. Bigger ranks mean, intuitively, that the relation is "closer to being ill-founded". The point is that Borel sets have a kind of "overspill" property: sets of fixed Borel rank that contain reals coding well-founded relations of too high rank, also contain reals coding ill-founded relations. And this means that the set $S_{WF}$ is not, in fact, Borel.

This is of course *not a proof* - the details are much more complicated. But this is the idea: there's a connection between the complexity of a Borel set, and its ability to distinguish well-founded relations from ill-founded ones.

This motivates the following general intuition:

> If I have a set defined in terms of quantification *over infinite sequences*, rather than only over natural numbers, then that set probably isn't Borel.

There are of course counterexamples, but this is a good rule of thumb. And the example you mention, of course, is of this kind. It's kind of the opposite of $S_{WF}$: $S_{WF}$ was defined by saying that there is *no* sequence of a certain form, whereas your set is defined by saying that there *is* a sequence of a certain form. So a natural thing to do is try to find a Borel isomorphism between your set and the complement of $S_{WF}$.

Comment: Unless I overlooked a negation somewhere in the definitions, $S_{WF}$ is not analytic but co-analytic.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Dangit! Of course you're right, I was typing too fast. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helps giving a better idea of what is behind. I think that the difficulty I have to understand intuitively the failure of being Borel starts early in the argument. I have only a very basic intuition of being Borel, which is based on the topology of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: ... Basically, I "feel" (intuitively) that a Borel is something that can be constructed by iteration of a process of the form : take countable unions or intersections of sets built from taking countable unions or intersections of sets built from... (etc.) ...from open or closed sets of $\mathbb{R}$. When we work with $2^\omega$ instead, I kind of lose my (topological) intuition. For example, I don't "see" why $S_{linear}$ is closed.

Comment: @Jon-S Borel sets work the same way in $2^\omega$ - the topology is slightly different, but the Borel sets are constructed in the same way from it. (In case you're not aware: the topology on $2^\omega$ is generated by basic clopen sets of the form $\{f\in 2^\omega: \sigma\prec f\}$ for $\sigma$ a finite binary string. So, e.g., the set of all infinite binary strings beginning "$01001$" is open and closed in $2^\omega$. More generally, if I have a tree $T\subseteq 2^{<\omega}$ of finite binary strings, the set of paths through $T$ is closed; and every closed set has this form.) (cont'd)

Comment: Now, as to why $S_{linear}$ is closed, this is a nice argument. What does a real $r$ have to do to be in $S_{linear}$? Well, first let's think about what a *relation* $R$ on $\mathbb{N}$ has to do to be a linear order. We need: (1) if $(a, b)\in R$, then $(b, a)\not\in R$ (I'm thinking of $R$ as "$<$" rather than "$\le$", here). (2) If $(a, b)\in R$ and $(b, c)\in R$, then $(a, c)\in R$. (3) For all $a\not=b$, either $(a, b)\in R$ or $(b, a)\in R$. (cont'd)

Comment: Now, these are three "big" requirements, but they split into countably many "small" requirements - like $$\mbox{$(*)$ "If $(2, 5)\in R$ and $(5, 631)\in R$, then $(2, 631)\in R$".}$$ Since intersections of closed sets are closed, it's enough to show that each individual requirement of this form corresponds to a closed set - for example, we want that the set of $f\in 2^\omega$ coding an $R$ satisfying $(*)$ from above is closed. Well, $(*)$ is a condition on bits: suppose $\langle 2, 5\rangle=0$, $\langle 5, 631\rangle=1$ and $\langle 2, 631\rangle=2$ for simplicity. Then $(*)$ says (contd)

Comment: "The sequence $f$ **must not begin** "$110$" (that is, Yes Yes No)." That is, $(*)$ says that $f$ must not lie in the open set generated by "$110$", so $(*)$ corresponds to a closed set! More generally, each "small" requirement says something about what finitely many bits of $f$ can't be - and it's a good exercise to show that any such requirement corresponds to a small set. Being a linear order is determined by universal statements "$\forall a, b$...". These correspond to intersections, and atomic formulas like "$aRb$" are clopen. So being a linear order is an intersection of clopens: closed.

Comment: Noah, I'm curious what exactly you mean by this: "The point is that Borel sets have a kind of "overspill" property: sets of fixed Borel rank that contain reals coding well-founded relations of too high rank, also contain reals coding ill-founded relations." Is there someplace I can read a more precise version of this statement?

Comment: @WillBrian It's just $\Sigma^1_1$-bounding relativized to the Borel code. Suppose $\sigma$ is a real coding a Borel set $B_\sigma$ which contains only (reals that represent) well-founded relations. Let $\alpha$ be the least $\sigma$-noncomputable ordinal. If any well-ordering of ordertype $\ge\alpha$ were in $B_\sigma$, we would be able to determine which $\sigma$-computable linear orders are well-orders in a $\Sigma^1_1$-in-$\sigma$ way, namely by asking whether the order in question embedded into some element fo $B_\sigma$. This can't happen, by (relativized) $\Sigma^1_1$ bounding.

Comment: OK, thanks. That makes sense, although it's not what I was hoping you meant. (I was hoping you were going to tell me something along the lines of: there is some $\alpha$ such that if $B$ is a $G_\delta$ set containing only well-founded relations, then $B$ contains no relations of rank $\geq \alpha$ (and similarly for other classes beyond $G_\delta$).)

Comment: @WillBrian Nothing like that can be true: consider a singleton whose element codes a really big ordinal. It's the lightface complexity, not topological complexity, that is essential here.

Comment: You're right. I meant something a little different from what I wrote: There is some $\alpha$ such that if $B$ is a $G_\delta$ set containing only well-founded relations, then $B$ cannot contain all relations of rank $<\alpha$ (and similarly for other classes beyond $G_\delta$). I don't suppose you know of any restrictions like this?